# Efficiently searching a LARGE GeoJson file to see if it contains a point (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, mapkit, geojson

I have a 200mb geojson file containing the speed limits of a country. In short the file has polygons that encompass different areas with each polygon having a given speed limit value.

I am creating a ios swift naviagation app that needs to query this geojson file to get the speed limit the user is in. My current approach is somwhat of a linear search so whilst working induces lag and massive peformance hits to the program.

My current implementation:

```
func findSpeedLimit(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, geoJSON: GeoJSON) -> Int? {
    // Decode the GeoJSON data into a FeatureCollection object
    guard case let .featureCollection(featureCollection) = geoJSON else {
        print("Error: GeoJSON data is not a FeatureCollection")
        return nil
    }
    
    // Create a Point object from the location coordinates
    let point = Point(x: location.longitude, y: location.latitude)
    //print("Looking for speed limit at location: \(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)")
    
    // Loop through the features in the feature collection
    for (index, feature) in featureCollection.features.enumerated() {
        // Check if the feature has a geometry and properties
        guard let geometry = feature.geometry,
              let properties = feature.properties else {
            print("Feature \(index) has no geometry or properties")
            continue
        }
        
        do {
            // Check if the geometry contains the point
            if try geometry.contains(point) {
                // Check if the properties have a speedLimitZoneValue key
                if let speedLimit = properties["speedLimitZoneValue"] {
                    let speedLimitString = String(describing: speedLimit)
                    if let number = Int(speedLimitString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()) {
                        //print (number)
                        //print("Speed limit found for feature \(index): \(number) km/h")
                        return number
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    print("Feature \(index) has no 'speedLimitZoneValue' property")
                }
            } else {
                //print("Feature \(index) does not contain the point")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error checking if geometry contains point: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Update: have implemented prepared geometries with help from others in the geoSwift library: https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift/pull/264

Comment: An efficient binary search is only possible if the array is sorted.

Comment: @vadian How would suggest I sort the geoJson file then?

Comment: Iterating thousands of geometries for every location update is clearly a poor approach. At least save the last matching geometry since it will likely match the next few location updates. But otherwise you need a way to index all of the geometries or split them up into a more efficient tree structure to quickly narrow down the list of geometries to allow for much smaller iterations.

Comment: I have no experience with any specific libraries but one would hope that there is a GeoJSON implementation out there that already provides an efficient search of matching geometries given a location. The trick of course is to find such a library.

Comment: @HangarRash I tried to implement somthing of a rtree but struggled. And using swift/ios couldn't find many library to help

Comment: Check GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=geojson+language%3ASwift&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=Swift&l=

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks for the Link! As it showed I am currently using the GeoSwift library to load in and search the geojson individual features for points however there is no specific function to "provide an efficient search of matching geometries given a location" as we need. Such thing needs to be built from scratch it appears - the issue I'm struggling with

Comment: Here's another idea - put the geometries in a SQLite database using its RTree support. See https://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html for details and example. SQLite also supports a geoJSON extension to the RTree module but the version included in iOS doesn't have that extension.

Comment: Last one and I'll leave you alone. :) See https://github.com/Outdooractive/gis-tools for a Swift GeoJSON library that seems to have RTree queries that may meet your needs. Good luck.

Comment: I used https://github.com/Bersaelor/KDTree to create a spacial index. Extremely fast. Since I use it for point coordinates, my implementation isn't too useful for you. Takes  0.01 seconds to index my 3000 coordinates, searching in that index is almost immeasurable.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same problem. For Android, Turfjs exists. I found a native port of this for Swift: https://github.com/mapbox/turf-swift. They also conveniently provide `Codable` support for `FeatureCollection`, `GeoJSONDocument`s, and others.

Comment: Thanks mate! I ended up using Geos and Geoswift. See my above update:

Update: have implemented prepared geometries with help from others in the geoSwift library: https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift/pull/264